# Issue Referencing Column in VBA SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that I'm trying to perform SQL queries on. I get "no value given for one or more required parameters", so I think it's a problem with my query. I can do a query like "SELECT * FROM [Employee$A2:A4]", but when I reference a particular column using the name (i.e. name, title...etc, or even using the generic column reference like F1) I get "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Here's my code:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT Employee FROM [Employee$] AS e WHERE e.Skill_Title = " & """" & skillTitle & """" & " AND e.Branch = " & """" & branchTitle & """" & " AND e.Skill_Prof = 5"

rs.Open strSQL, cn
MsgBox (rs.GetString)
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Are your headers in row 2 or 1?

Comment: They're in row 1

Comment: Try single quotes around your query values

Comment: Here's something interesting, when I try strSQL = "SELECT Name FROM [Employee$A2:D4]", it fails, but when I try SELECT * FROM [Employee$A2:D4]" it works just fine. Let me try single quotes

Comment: does `select [name]….where [name]…` work?

Comment: Just a thought - your sheet appears to be named employee in the code, is it actually employees with an s? Oh and 'Name' is a reserved word so that might be a problem - try changing the heading to EmpName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the following example.

Tell me if the problem persists and the inputs you're using.

I have this on Employee sheet:

[image]

Created "MyQuery" subprocess as follows (as you can see, this is a replica of your code, with some little differences):

```
Sub MyQuery(ByVal skillTitle As String, _
            ByVal branchTitle As String, _
            ByVal skillProf As Integer)

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    strCon = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strFile & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;" & _
        "HDR=Yes;" & _
        "IMEX=1"";"

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Cn.Open strCon

    strSQL = _
        "SELECT Employee " & _
        "FROM [Employee$] AS e " & _
        "WHERE e.Skill_Title = '" & skillTitle & "' AND " & _
               "e.Branch = '" & branchTitle & "' AND " & _
               "e.Skill_Prof = " & CStr(skillProf)

    Rs.Open strSQL, Cn

    MsgBox (Rs.GetString)

    'Do not forget closing your connection'
    Rs.Close
    Cn.Close

End Sub
```

Made a quick test:

```
Sub test()
    'Try running this'
    Call MyQuery("FOUR", "Y", 5)

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you named the columns?  I wasn't sure from your code example whether you had named the columns or were assuming the column header would suffice for a reference.  A "named" column is not the same as using a column header.  To access the column by name try assigning a name to the column first.

From: [How to give a name to the columns in Excel](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/give-name-columns-excel-73447.html)

- Click the letter of the column you want to change and then click the "Formulas" tab.
- Click "Define Name" in the Defined Names group in the Ribbon to open the New Name window.
- Enter the new name of the column in the Name text box.

Comment: Good point. I do have my columns named. employee refers to Table1[Employee], skill_prof is Table1[Skill Prof] and so forth